# onclick event returns undefined function

Tags: javascript, onclick, undefined

I am building a demo movie app so I decided to assign onclick events with a function that gets me some movie related data.
The problem arises when I click on the target links I want to work on, giving me back an undefined function.
Here's the code:

```
    function getMovieList(key,value) { console.log(key,value)}
    
    function getLanguages() {
        const languagesList = document.querySelector("[languages]");
        
        const languagesArray = [
            ["en-US", "english"],
            ["it", "italian"],
            ["de", "german"],
            ["hi", "indian"],
        ];
    
        const languagesMap = new Map();
    
        languagesArray.forEach( languages => {
            const [idLanguage,language] = languages;
            languagesMap.set(idLanguage,language);
    
            languagesList.innerHTML += `
             <li class="capitalize" onclick="getMovieList(with_original_langauge=${idLanguage}, ${language})">
                <a href="index.html" language-id=${idLanguage}">${language}</a>
            </li>
        `;
       
        } );
    }
getLanguages()
```

When I  inspect my links they do have the given arguments but if I click on them, then it says my function is undefined so I cannot get the values back.
Why is that ?

I tried the method window.onload expecting to load the function beforehand and get it as defined,but still it did not work.

Comment: Please create a complete snippet with tool `[<>]`

Comment: I agree with @SimoneRossaini. If you include a complete code snippet, it'll make it easier for us to help you. Not enough info currently. Based on the error, I'll venture a guess that your script that includes the 'getMovieList' function isn't loading properly or at all.

Comment: I even tried to add  an event listener to  <li>  elements but still it does not work,anyway I have updated my code.

Comment: If you could explain exactly what you want as output, please show what result you expect here! @Ajeje
A snippet is welcome too!
Don't hesitate to check the errors one by one in the console!

Answer (score 1):

The `getMovieList()` function is called asynchronously, which means that the default behaviour of the `<a>` link is called before the function is executed.

Use `event.preventDefault();` in the event handler, and change the `href` manually from the function body.

```js
function getMovieList() {
  alert('movie list');
  location.href="index.html";
  }
```

```html
<li>
   <a href="index.html" onclick="event.preventDefault();getMovieList()">language</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : My answer have changed since your edit!

There's something that looks at your code but you have to add  a real `location.href` in the function.

Here it makes just an alert with some URL parameters for the demo.

```js
    let languagesListDiv;
        
    let languagesArray = [
            ["en", "english"],
            ["it", "italian"],
            ["de", "german"],
            ["hi", "indian"]
        ];
    
    let languagesMap = new Map();
    let result = "";
    
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",run);
        
    function getMovieList(key,value){
        console.log("key = " + key + ", value = " + value)
    }
    function alertMovieList(key,value){
        alert("location.href=\"http://yourLinkHere.test?key=" + key + "&value=" + value + "\"")
    }
    function run(e){
        languagesListDiv = document.getElementById("languagesListDiv");
        getLanguages();
    }
    function getLanguages() {
    languagesArray.forEach( languages => {
    languagesListDiv.innerHTML += `<li class="capitalize"><a href="index.html"  onclick="event.preventDefault();alertMovieList('${languages[0]}','${languages[1]}')">key = ${languages[0]}, value = ${languages[1]}</a></li>`;
    getMovieList(languages[0],languages[1]);
        });
    }
```

```html
<ul id="languagesListDiv">
    
</ul>
```

Comment: It does not work in any case, it keeps telling me that the function alertMovieList is undefined . Anyway meanwhile I found a solution : 
My function was declared within the script "index.js" and was the only script where I was running my functions from.
Then I created another script "global.js", loaded into my "index.html" and now it works fine,I am able to see my function.
Just to clarify better, now in my index.html I have : 

`<script src="../js/app/global.js" defer></script>

<script type="module" src="../js/app/index.js" defer></script>`

Comment: @Ajeje The console log : Uncaught TypeError: languagesList is null when I run your code.
I'm not sure about what can give a variable declared so : ```const [idLanguage,language]```